# Best method to convert a string rapresentation of binary chars to a string of chars

Tags: c++, locale

I created a custom numpunct class that allows me to create a custom numpunct with user defined values (in my case the thousands separator, decimal separator and the grouping will be read from a xml document).
Here's my class:

```
class custom_numpunct : public std::numpunct<char>
{
public:
  custom_numpunct(const char decimal_point, const char thousands_sep, const std::string grouping)
    : cDecimalPoint(decimal_point), cThousandsSep(thousands_sep), sGroup(grouping) {}
protected:
  virtual char do_decimal_point() const { return cDecimalPoint; }
  virtual char do_thousands_sep() const { return cThousandsSep; }
  virtual std::string do_grouping() const { return sGroup; }
  const char cDecimalPoint;
  const char cThousandsSep;
  const std::string sGroup;
};
```

The main problem is that grouping accept binary characters to do the grouping.
So if I use a value directly from the code like

```
std::string grouping = "\1\2\3";
```

it works because they are binary values. The problem is that reading from user input I will have

```
std::string grouping = "\\1\\2\\3";
```

(the user insert \1\2\3)
So I need something to convert a string binary rapresentation to the actual characters.
I created this function

```
std::string convertToBinary(std::string input)
{
  std::stringstream out;
  std::stringstream ss(input);
  std::string tok;
  int value;

  while (std::getline(ss, tok, '\\')) 
  {
    if (!tok.empty())
    {
      try 
      {
        value = std::stoi(tok);
      }
      catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) 
      {
        std::cerr << "Invalid argument: " << ia.what() << std::endl;
        continue;
      }
      out << (char)(value & 0xff);
    }
  }
  return out.str();
}
```

It splits the string with \ and try to convert the single integer to the character using a string but it might not be reliable (also 1 is a valid binary input).
There are better methods to do this conversion?

Comment: Let's be very precise.  When you say this: `std::string grouping = "\\1\\2\\3";` that is actually the string "\1\2\3".  So what is the actual, character content of the string you're reading?  Does it have single backslashes or doubles?  What do you mean when you say "it isn't reliable"?

Comment: "It isn't reliable" is not a problem description.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I wrote it wrong. I'm not sure if it is reliable or not.Isn't also '1' a valid binary char? also with `std::string grouping = "\\1\\2\\3";` I mean that the user actually insert the string "\1\2\3" in the xml document. The input string has single backslash

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
string convertToBinary(const string& in)
{
    string out;
    out.reserve(in.size() / 2);

    for (const char *cur = in.c_str(), *end = cur + in.size(); cur != end; ++cur) {
        if (*cur == '\\') {
            ++cur; // skip first backslash                                                                              
            if (cur == end) {
                break;
            }

            if (isdigit(*cur)) { // found escape sequence                                                               
                char* end;
                unsigned long num = strtol(cur, &end, 10);
                cur = end - 1;
                out.push_back(num);
                continue;
            }
        }

        out.push_back(*cur);
    }

    return out;
}
```

If I call `convertToBinary("\\1\\233")` I get a string with two bytes, namely 1 and 233 decimal.  Any backslash not followed by a number is skipped, so e.g. `"\\n"` becomes `"n"`.

The `reserve()` call at the top can be tuned according to your typical input data.  If your inputs are always full of escape sequences, e.g. `"\\1\\10\\100"` you may want to divide by 3 instead, but if your inputs may not have many escapes, you may want to just use the full `in.size()`.